# React Child component's function processes old props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a Wordle game on React and i stuck with a problem.
I have a parent component (App) that passes its state of `gameBoard` to the child component (GameComponent) via props like this:

```
const [gameBoard, setGameBoard] = useState(new MainGameBoard(difficulty))
```

Inside my GameComponent i receive these `gameBoard` and `setGameBoard` as props.
Basically, all the things GameComponent does are rendering the letter containers of `gameBoard` and invoking `setGameBoard` to a `nextBoard` whenever player types something (keydown event listener) via this function:

```
function updateBoard(){
        const nextBoard = gameBoard.getBoardCopy()
        setGameBoard(nextBoard)
    }
```

I hang the event listener on the `document` after the first render of GameComponent like this:

```
useEffect(() => document.addEventListener(‘keydown’, handleKeyDown), []
)

    function handleKeyDown(e:
    globalThis.KeyboardEvent){
        const inputLetter = e.key.toUpperCase()
        if(inputLetter === 'BACKSPACE'){
        if (currentLetter.current - 1 < 0) return
        const letterBox = gameBoard.getLetterBox(currentLetter.current - 1, currentWord.current)
            letterBox.letter = null
            currentLetter.current--
        } else if (inputLetter !== 'ENTER' && isAllowedLetter(inputLetter)){
            if (currentLetter.current >= gameBoard.riddledWord.length) return
            const letterBox = gameBoard.getLetterBox(currentLetter.current, currentWord.current)
            letterBox.letter = inputLetter
            currentLetter.current++
        } else if (inputLetter === 'ENTER'){
            if (currentLetter.current !== gameBoard.riddledWord.length) return
            calculateResult(gameBoard.riddledWord)
            currentWord.current++
            currentLetter.current = 0
        }
```

And here’s how `getBoardCopy` method looks like:

```
getBoardCopy(){
   const boardCopy = new MainGameBoard(this.letterBoxQty)
   boardCopy.letterBoxes = this.letterBoxes
   boardCopy.words = this.words
   boardCopy.riddledWord = this.riddledWord
   return boardCopy
```

This parent component also has a `difficulty` state. Whenever the `difficulty` changes, it must `setGameBoard` to a new, totally empty instance of MainGameBoard class with more or less letter containers . I implemented this logic via `useEffect` with dependencies array of `difficulty` and `restartGame` function like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    restartGame()
  }, [difficulty])

  function restartGame() {
    const nextGameBoard = new MainGameBoard(difficulty)
    nextGameBoard.initLetterBoxes()
    nextGameBoard.riddleWord()
    setGameBoard(nextGameBoard)
}
```

So, on this step my child component rerenders properly, everytime the player changes current difficulty of the game, GameComponent receives a new empty `gameBoard`.
But when he tries to type something again, the current difficulty rolls back to initial, as if my `updateBoard` function stuck with the very first `gameBoard` prop passed from the parent component after the first render. Is there any solution for this problem? I hope it is.. :(

I tried to set the received `gameBoard` prop to the local state of my GameComponent, update it via `useEffect` and use it inside my `updateBoard` function as i saw on some similar topic, but unfortunately no results seen

Comment: What is the value of `difficulty` when the user types?  Is it possible that the `difficulty` value is reverting?  You haven't explained what that value is or how it is stored.  Consider putting a `console.log("difficulty is:", difficulty)` in the parent component so that you see the value with each render.

Comment: @GregFenton Difficulty is being stored as a state. When user types something it stays the same in both parent and child component as needed. But console.log inside updateBoard function logs initial value of difficulty

Comment: Looking it all over, I'd be interested to know what `.getBoardCopy()` looks like. Also, make sure that the "new empty board" that the child gets is actually set to the difficulty you think it should be. Lastly, I would look at whether the onChange handler from the typing is changing things inadvertently.  Feel free to update your question with all these data points.

Comment: @GregFenton Updated. Of course, the empty board is set to the correct difficulty, but it is not only about the difficulty, but the whole nextBord object inside updateBoard function remains with the same properties whether letterBoxQty (difficulty)or riddledWord, words, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been resolved by changing the `useEffect` inside my GameComponent from

```
useEffect(() => document.addEventListener(‘keydown’, handleKeyDown), [])
```

to

```
useEffect(() => {
   document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
   return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
})
```